# JSON response data length getting undefined error in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, response

I want to get the length of `language` in JavaScript alert box -

See screenshot-

Ajax Response -

[image]

[image]

My Ajax code -

```
function search_menu(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: rootUrl() + "rest_apis/search_menu.json", 
        cache: false,        
        success: function(res){ //alert(data.data[0].language[142]);
            var len = res.data[0].language.length; 
            alert(len); //Showing undefined
        },
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

I am just alerting `alert(lang)` its showing undefined. Actually in language having 36 record. why its showing `undefined`?

Comment: Your code is wrong should be:

var len = res.data[0].language; ?

Comment: Try res[0].language.length;

Comment: @Kumar — That definitely won't work.

Comment: @Kumar your code not working. :(

Comment: See my answer below : Object.keys(res.data[0].language).length

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try : `Object.keys(res.data[0].language).length`

Live example :

```js
var res = {
        "data" : [
                {
                  "language" : { "107":"english", "142":"hindi", "143" : "indonesian"}
                }
        ]
}


alert("There are " + Object.keys(res.data[0].language).length + " languages." )
```

Comment: Just a bit perplexed as to why the .length property works on another page, while only your answer works on a particular one of mine. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `Object.keys().forEach();`.count your json length.[....CHeck to click here....](http://jsfiddle.net/6Yj5h/2475/)

```
var json={"data":[{"language":{"190":"english","191":"gujarati"}}]};
var length=0;
Object.keys(json.data[0].language).forEach(function(key) {
  length++; 
});
alert(length);
```

Comment: What's the "use_native_lan" variable for? Why don't you just replace "forEach(function(key) { length++;});" with just ".length" ? It would be cleaner, faster, and...well, that would be my answer :)

Comment: @JeremyThille, Sorry for that(now I changed),offcourse,it better solution,This is an another solution to find length.

Comment: Sure, it works; but it's just slower, more code, more lines, more variables, more complicated. In one word it's just less elegant. So I was wondering about its interest?

Comment: @JeremyThille,verify my code..I am using `Native Javascript`.  `Object.keys().length` internally counting length(it means it use for loop). but `Object.keys().forEach(function(){ //do your stuff })`. you can add your own stuff inside function.so,I think both is doing same job.

Answer (score 2):

```
var res={"data":[{"language":{"190":"english","191":"gujarati"}}]};
console.log( Object.keys(res['data'][0].language).length);
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4e529kdo/2/)**

Comment: Great, that's exactly my answer :)

Comment: Downvoter comment will help me to improve my answer.

Comment: I don't understand why people get sanctioned by downvotes so quickly, when they're just trying to help. My answer, although correct and later validated by the OP, was immediately downvoted twice. Those downvotes are just unfair.

Answer (score 1):

You misspelt `language` as `languge`, which is why it is `undefined`.

Even if you had not, it is an object not an array, so it doesn't have a `length` property. You'll need to count the keys to find out how many there are.

Comment: After your edit, you should not get the result you describe. You should get `[Object object]` alerted.

Comment: After your second edit: See the second paragraph of my answer.

Comment: Sorry there are typing mistake.